# Nodejs save connected sockets on rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js

As far as we know creation of sockets is unique id.when my users create room and invite users to join into that. I cant save and store joined users on rooms.when user joined on room (s)he likes to server store this join and after disconnet and connected again joined automatically to latest joined rooms.how can i store sockets and join automatically users?

I cant find any solution about this ability. Because sockets changed on each connection.

Is any simple solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some sort of userID for each user and, usually store that in a cookie.  Then, if you want persistent rooms, you have to create your own server-side data structure that keeps track of which rooms you want each user to be in.  And, each time you add or remove a user from a room, you can modify your own data structure so it is properly keeping track of that state.

Then, when a user connects, you can get their userID from the cookie and look in your data structure to see what rooms you should put that connection in.  Then, to keep memory management in check, you have to somehow expire users from your data structure after some period of inactivity so they don't stay in there forever.  (probably you timestamp when they last visited and then hourly you walk through the data structure and remove users who haven't visited in awhile).

If you want this information to also survive a server restart, then you have to save it persistently to disk and then reload that information upon startup.  If you're already using a database as part of your app, you can store the info in a database or, if not, you can just write your internal data structure out to disk every so often, probably as JSON and then read that in when your server starts.